# Pass object contain date with ajax comes null

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using Ajax request to send the value of Object contain Datetime to my API Controller here is my ajax call

```
                 $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                            url: "/Generate/Create",
                            data: { charge: testData },
                            success: function (){},
                    });
```

And here is my api controller

```
    [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateCharge(Charge charge)
        {

            charge.Created = DateTime.UtcNow;

            return Json(new { result = charge });

        }
```

when I reached to the controller it is showing null value for Datetime please take a look on the below image

[image]

Question:

How i can get the value which i passed from ajax request !!

Update :

testData object is :

[image]

Comment: The question is: what exactly is being *sent* (which you've not included).  What's `testData`?  Or what's `testData.ArticleGroups`?  Or what's `testData.ArticleGroups[0]`?  (in the javascript)

Comment: ok i will update my question which console.log(testData)

Comment: i hope that make sence now .

Comment: @freedomn-m i tried to convert date but didnot work .

Comment: Yes, this is a common issue, the C# default serialiser doesn't output dates "correctly" giving that horrid string "/Date()/".  The answer is to change your serialiser to use newtonsoft (or other) so that they are generated in your json/js correctly in the first place.   More details: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx (unfortunately Microsoft not only broke this, they've now also broken the link to the fix... *facepalm*)

Comment: As an aside... If the code is just accepting the previous output without any user modification (for example, if that output value wasn't used to populate a date picker or input element of any kind), then why do you need that value returned to the server?  Or to put it another way, where is your JavaScript code getting this value that has the default .NET serialization formatting?